# What is the maximum number of column being supported by apache spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

SPARK-Version: 1.5.2 with yarn 2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557

I'm running into a problem while I'm exploring the data through spark-shell that I'm trying to create a really fat dataframe that with 3000 columns. Code as below:

```
val valueFunctionUDF = udf((valMap: Map[String, String], dataItemId: String) =>
  valMap.get(dataItemId) match {
  case Some(v) => v.toDouble
  case None => Double.NaN
})
```

s1 is being the main dataframe and the schema as below:

```
|-- combKey: string (nullable = true)
|-- valMaps: map (nullable = true)
|    |-- key: string
|    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

after I run the code:

```
dataItemIdVals.foreach{w =>
 s1 = s1.withColumn(w, valueFunctionUDF($"valMaps", $"combKey"))}
```

my terminal just stuck after the above column with the info being printed out:

```
16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on 172.22.49.20:41494 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.2 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:43026 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:44890 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:52020 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:33272 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:48481 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:44026 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:34539 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.0 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:43734 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:42769 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:60603 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:59102 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:47578 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:43149 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:52488 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on xxxxx:52298 in memory (size: 7.6 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 9
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on 172.22.49.20:41494 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.2 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:33272 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:59102 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:44026 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:42769 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:43149 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:43026 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:52298 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:42890 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:47578 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:60603 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:43734 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:48481 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:52020 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:52488 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.1 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on xxxxx:34539 in memory (size: 7.3 KB, free: 5.0 GB)
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 8
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned shuffle 0
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 7
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 6
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 5
 16/07/11 12:20:54 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 4
```

Nothing is going on on sparkUI and I guess spark is calculating some metadata for the new dataframe(number of column etc.)? Anyone seen this kind of issue before? Anyway to get around with it?